# Copying ansible keypair public key to existing AWS instances

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, ansible

We have around 10 instances already running on AWS using my personal AWS keypair `justin.pem`.

I am setting up an Ansible box, and generated a new AWS keypair called `ansible.pem`. I copied `ansible.pem` to the Ansible instance into .ssh and have it ready to use.

The problem is how do I inject the `ansible.pem` public key into `.ssh/authorized_keys` on each of our existing AWS instances?

When we create new instances, I want to assign the `justin.pem` key pair, but this means that Ansible won't be able to ssh into newly created instances as well.

What is the solution to this? Seems like a chicken and egg problem.

Comment: Does the authorized_keys module work with pem keys? I had trouble with it.

Answer (score 3):

Create new instances with the `ansible.pem` public key, and then use [Ansible's authorized_keys module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/authorized_key_module.html) to distribute any additional public keys you want to access your instance with, such as the corresponding public key for `justin.pem`.

```
- name: Install justin's ssh key
  authorized_key: user=ec2-user
                  key="{{lookup('file', '/home/justin/.ssh/justin.pub')}}"
```